# iPhone - openAL stops playing if I record with AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, openal, avaudiorecorder

this is an iPhone-related question:
I use openAL to play some sound (I have to manage gain, pitch, etc.).
I want to record what I'm playing and I use AVAudioRecorder but when I "prepareToRecord" openAL stops to play audio.
What's the problem?
Here is the record IBAction I use:

```
- (IBAction) record: (id) sender
{
NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey]; 
    [settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:FILEPATH];
    self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
    self.recorder.delegate = self;
    self.recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [self.recorder prepareToRecord];
    [self.recorder record];
}
```

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried with AudioQueue recording too.
This time sounds stops after this code:

```
status = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(recordState.queue, recordState.buffers[i], 0, NULL);
```

So it's possible to record when iPhone is playing with openAL???

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

FILEPATH is same as path where another file is being played...?
and if `record` and `prepareToRecord` are called from same place... actually you do not need to call `prepareToRecord`... `record` will do the job... 
see

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/prepareToRecord

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

No FILEPATH points to Documents folder and the played file is in the Bundle. I tried to comment prepareToRecord but it still stops.

I found that when I run record, alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state); returns always AL_PLAYING for state.

So for openAL the file is still playing.